# What is the difference between commit --amend and reset --soft

Tags: git

The idea of my question is researching...
What is the essential difference between `commit --amend` and `reset --soft`

Investigation process in steps:

```
vim index.js > edit > save
git add index.js
git commit -m '...'
git push origin
```

Now I need to rewrite the commit I've sent previously. For that matter I should use:

```
vim index.js > edit > save
git add index.js
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push --force origin
```

Essentially I've got another one SHA1 and for the sake of analogy three `objects` in `.git/objects` directory, but the `git log` shows me two SHA1 and I totally agree with it because the commit has been amended.

Let's go back a bit. Instead of `git commit --amend` I've executed the `git reset --soft HEAD~`, the HEAD pointer stands for `stage` version of the file, write some code and execute:

```
git add index.js > git commit -m '...' > git push --force origin
```

.git/objects directory contains one more SHA1, but the history has been amended with the new one.

So the way I'm telling that the commands `git commit --amend` and `git reset --soft` have **the same behavior**

Or I'm not right?

Comment: There is quote from official git [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History): "don’t amend your last commit if you’ve already pushed it"

Comment: `git commit --amend` and `git reset --soft` do very different things. However, `git reset --soft` followed by `git commit` produces results similar to `git commit --amend`.

Comment: @LeszekMazur, sir, you should definitely add to your quote's reference `if your project has the collaborators`... in other way you still can invoke `--amend` after you push it

Answer (score 7):

Both commands can be used to achieve a similar end goal, but they don't do the same thing.  `git commit --amend` makes a new commit with whatever be in the stage, and that new commit *replaces* whatever commit were the previous HEAD of your branch.

On the other hand, `git reset --soft` moves the HEAD pointer of the branch back one commit, but leaves both the stage and working directory intact.  This has the effect that your branch now appears to be on the previous commit, but all the work you did to generate the old HEAD commit now appears as being staged.  If you now change things in the working directory, stage those changes, and commit, you would also be making a new commit to replace the old HEAD, which is a similar result to `git commit --amend`.

One advantage which `git reset --soft` (which is identical to saying `git reset --soft HEAD~1`) has over `git commit --amend`, is that the former can reset across *multiple* commits.  This can be useful if you want to rewrite say the latest 4 commits in your branch.  On the other hand, `git commit --amend` is a one horse show, and only works on the HEAD commit.

Comment: one benefit of `git commit --amend` is you don't lose the commit message and need to type it out again. also makes it easy to see the correction-diff (`git commit`, edit x, `git diff`, `git commit --amend x`, etc.)

Comment: @AD7six For the commit message, `git commit` has `-c <commit-ish>`(editable) and `-C <commit-ish>`(uneditable) to reuse the commit message of `commit-ish`.

Comment: @ElpieKay: I often use `git commit --amend --no-edit` to stuff a quick one-line fix into a commit when I notice a typo in my `git show` output, to retain my previous commit message.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the essential difference between commit --amend and reset --soft

One does a commit, the other does a reset?

This is a deliberate sort of joke answer, but it's actually the right one as well.  They are simply different operations.

To understand all of this properly, you need to understand Git's *index*, how Git actually makes commits, and the way *branch names* work.  It helps to start with a clear definition of what a commit is and does.

#### Git is all about commits; branch names just point to one commit, each

People new to Git often think Git is about files, or branches.  It's definitely *not* about files (though it does store them), and the word *branch* is ambiguous and Git isn't really about the meaning most Git newcomers use either.  Git is really all about *commits*.  The commit is the fundamental user-oriented unit of storage in Git.<sup>1</sup>

Each commit stores a snapshot—a full and complete copy of *all* of your files—plus some metadata, which provides information about the commit: who made it and when, for instance.  Each commit gets a unique hash ID, reserved forevermore to mean *that* commit.  Every Git repository everywhere agrees that *that* hash ID means *that* commit, and either a repository has that commit and therefore has that hash ID, or it doesn't, and doesn't.  Once made, no commit—in fact, no internal Git object at all—can ever change either.  So the snapshot is frozen forever in time.

Every commit can contain, in its metadata, the hash ID(s) of some earlier, pre-existing commit(s).  These are the commit's *parent commits*.  Most commits store just one parent hash ID.  These linkages, from child backwards to parent, form chains:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

If we're at commit `H`, we can read out its parent hash ID `G`.  This allows Git to look up commit `G`; `G` contains the hash ID of its parent, `F`.  This allows Git to look up commit `F`, which contains its parent hash ID.  By repeating this process, Git can work all the way from the *last* commit back to the *first* one.<sup>2</sup>

This means we only need to remember the *last* commits.  There might be more than one "last commit", as in this case:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

Note that `H` is the last commit on `master`, while `J` is the last commit on `develop`.  The *branch names* select these *tip* commits.  From here, Git can work backwards.  Note that commit `G` is on *both* branches; this is perhaps clearer if we draw `H` on a row by itself:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

(these two drawings represent the same repository).

When there is more than one branch like this, we need a way to know *which one we've checked out* with `git checkout branch` or the newfangled `git switch branch`.  To keep track, we can draw the diagram with the special name `HEAD`, written in all uppercase like this, attached to one of the branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

This drawing means we are on branch `master` and have commit `H` checked out.

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

This drawing means we are on branch `develop` and have commit `J` checked out.

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits can be broken down into component parts—tree objects, blob objects, and the underlying commit objects that each refer to a tree object—but this level is not where users work with Git.

<sup>2</sup>Some commits—ones that Git calls *merge* commits—contain two or more hash IDs.  From such a commit, Git works backwards to *both* (or all) parents, introducing a fork in history.  Note how a merge, which brings things together, acts as a diverging point because Git works backwards.  Where branches diverge, as Git works backwards, this backwards traversal brings them back together.

At least one commit in every repository has *no* parent, because it was the first commit ever, and could not point backwards.  A commit with no parent is a *root commit*.

---

#### We make new commits from the *index*

As noted above, commits are frozen for all time: once we make a commit, we can never change it.  No part of any commit can ever change.<sup>3</sup>  This includes all the *files* stored inside each commit, in the snapshots.  They're not only frozen, they're also stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed format: no other programs on your computer can even *read* the files.

What this means is that Git *must* extract the files *from* a commit to somewhere that they become useful.  That somewhere is your work area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  Here, your files have their everyday form: they're not frozen, nor compressed; every computer program can use them.  You can do whatever you like with your work-tree: it is *yours* to work with, after all.

Git *could* make new commits from your work-tree.  Other version control systems do this.  But Git doesn't.  Instead, somewhere *between* the *current* commit—the one you checked out, from the branch you checked out, which Git finds with the special name `HEAD`, as we drew above—and the work-tree, Git stores all of your files in a special area that Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or—rarely these days—the *cache*.

These three names all refer to the same thing.  The index or staging area—I'll call it *index* here—holds copies of all of your committed files, at least initially.  They're in the frozen format, like they are in a commit,<sup>4</sup> but unlike a commit, they're not actually frozen: you can overwrite them.

So, every file has *three active versions:* the `HEAD` copy, frozen in the current commit; the index copy, which you can replace at any time; and the work-tree copy, which you can see and work on / with.  You edit the work-tree copy, then you run `git add file`.  You have to run `git add` all the time, and the reason is now clear: each `git add` you run *copies* the file, from the work-tree—where it has the everyday form your computer uses—to the index / staging-area, where it's in the frozen form Git likes.

Now we can see what `git commit` does, and why it's so relatively fast.<sup>5</sup>  All `git commit` has to do is package up what's already *in the index*, in the right format, into a new commit.  Well, first it has to gather a log message, and add your name and the current date-and-time and all that kind of stuff; and it has to set the new commit's parent hash ID, in the commit's metadata.  *Then* it can make the commit, using the pre-frozen files from the index.

The *parent* of the new commit is the current commit (except, as we'll see, for `--amend`).  The new commit—say, `K`—gets written into the collection of all commits, and it points back to the current commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
              \
               K
```

and now the magic bit happens: Git writes the *new* commit's hash ID into the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*.  In this case, that's `develop`, so now we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and `K` is the latest commit on `develop`.

---

<sup>3</sup>Note that even `git commit --amend` *doesn't* change a commit!  We will get to what it does do in a moment, but here is a hint.  If you do take out a commit, change something, and use that to make a new commit, you get a *different* commit with a different hash ID.  It does not matter *what* you change (except that different changes result in different hash IDs): any *different* commit will, by definition in Git, have a different hash ID.  Only if you keep every last bit the same—the same snapshot, the same author, the same log message, and the same date-and-time stamp—will you get the original hash ID back.  But then you haven't made a *new* commit: you made the *old* commit again, with the same parent, same snapshot, same log message, and even the same timestamps.  You made the original commit yesterday, and you just made the new one yesterday again—it's the same commit!

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the index holds *references to* the frozen copies: it just holds a blob hash ID, plus the name of the file, plus a bunch of cached information about the work-tree (hence the name *cache*).  The difference shows up if and when you start poking around with `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` and the like, to look at or change what's in the index.  Except for these cases, though, you can just think of the index as holding a copy of each file.

<sup>5</sup>If you've ever used some of the other pre-Git version control systems, you might remember how you can enter a "commit" or "checkout" type of command and go out to lunch because it's going to take many seconds or minutes to work.  These days, some people think Git is slow: they don't know *slow*.

---

#### What `git commit --amend` does

All `git commit --amend` really does is:

- write the new commit almost as usual, except
- instead of using the *current commit* as the parent of the new commit, use the *current commit's parent(s)* as the parent(s) of the new commit.

On top of this, it defaults to letting us edit the current commit's commit message, while making the new commit.

So suppose we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and you realize you forgot to `git add` a file, or you want to fix up the commit message.  You do your forgotten `git add` if needed, then run:

```
git commit --amend
```

Git goes to collect the commit message, but this time it opens the editor on a file holding commit `K`'s commit message.  You can edit this if necessary, write it out, and exit the editor, and `git commit` makes the new commit—but instead of setting its parent to `K`, it sets its parent to `K`'s parent(s), which means `J`.  This makes a new commit we can call either `L` or `K'`; let's use `K'`.  As its last step, `git commit` writes `K'`'s hash ID into the current branch name:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
              \
               K   [abandoned]
```

Note that *commit `K` still exists*, in the repository.  There's just no *branch name* by which we can *find* commit `K`.<sup>6</sup>  The name `develop` now points to commit `K'` instead.

So, `git commit --amend` *appears* to change a commit.  But all it really does is shove the commit aside, putting a new-and-improved (well, presumably) replacement in its stead.

---

<sup>6</sup>We can find `K`'s hash ID in the reflogs: the reflog for `develop` has it, at `develop@{1}`, at the moment, and the reflog for `HEAD` has it, at `HEAD@{1}`, at the moment.  Most Git commands don't look at the reflogs, though—and reflogs are optional, for that matter.  The reflog entries eventually expire, and once they are gone, commit `K` becomes *unprotected* from Git's Grim Collector, `git gc`, which garbage collects abandoned and unprotected commits and other lost Git objects.

What this means in the end is that usually, you can get back lost commits for at least 30 days, as that's the default minimum reflog entry keep-time.  It's `git gc` that normally handles all of this—including expiring old reflog entries—and Git runs `git gc` automatically, occasionally, if and when Git thinks it might be good to do.

---

#### `git reset` moves branch names, and optionally resets the index

The `git reset` command is considerably more complicated than `git commit --amend`, mostly because too many separate actions are all stuffed inside the one `git reset` command.  If we ignore most of them, though, and concentrate on `git reset`'s most fundamental mode of operation, what `git reset` does is to do up to three things:

1. First, it moves the current branch name.  You pick a commit—*any* commit in your repository, anywhere in the graph—and tell `git reset` that you want your current branch name, the one `HEAD` is attached-to, to point to *that* commit.  `git reset` makes that happen.
2. Then, if you said `--soft`, `git reset` stops.  Otherwise, it goes on to load the *index* from the commit you just told it to move to.
3. Then, if you said `--mixed`—or didn't say any of these—`git reset` stops.  Otherwise, it goes on to make your *work-tree* match the update it made to the index.

So, if we look at this graph:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

and run `git reset --soft HEAD~1`, the commit we selected was `J`: `HEAD~1` means *find the commit that `HEAD` selects* (which is `K`) *and step back one*, which lands at `J`.  So step 1 of `git reset` means *move `develop` to `J`*, which gives us this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
              \
               K   [abandoned]
```

Note how this looks very similar to what we got from `git commit --amend`, except there's no commit `K'` here.

We told `git reset` to reset with `--soft`, so at step 2, which would reset the index, it just quits instead.  The *index* is left alone.  Our *work-tree* is left alone.  If the index matched commit `K` a moment ago—and it probably did—then it still matches commit `K`.  If our work-tree matched commit `K`, it still does.  (If not, the work-tree doesn't really matter right now.)

If we now run `git commit`, Git will collect a log message as usual, package up whatever is in the index—which probably still matches `K`—and make a new commit.  Let's call that commit `K'`, and draw it in:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J--K'  <-- develop (HEAD)
              \
               K   [abandoned]
```

So in the end, we got here the same thing we would have gotten by `git commit --amend`: a new commit `K'` (with whatever hash ID it has) whose parent is `J` and whose contents are whatever was in the index.

#### So `--amend` and reset-and-commit are the same ... except when they're not

The `--amend` version is simpler: we run one command.  It also lets us amend a *merge commit*.  Suppose, for instance, we have this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L
```

We can use `git commit --amend` to shove `M` aside and make a new commit `M'`, using the index's contents (probably the same as `M`'s snapshot) and a new log message.  When we do, we get `M'` with parents `J` and `L`: two parents, i.e., a merge commit.  Without `--amend` it's kind of hard to get a merge commit,<sup>7</sup> and `git reset --soft` and another commit won't do it.

By the same token, though, `git commit --amend` will *only* look back *one* commit.  Using `git reset --soft`, we can make a bunch of commits "go away".  Suppose, for instance, we have this:

```
...--o--*--o   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

where the whole long chain of `A` through `I` were a bunch of experiments.  The feature now works and you'd like to have *one* commit `AI` that does it all.

There are multiple ways to achieve this,<sup>8</sup> but if you've just made commit `I`, so that your index and work-tree match commit `I`, you can now `git reset --soft HEAD~9` the name `feature` so that it points to commit `*`.  Then you can `git commit`, using the current index—the snapshot from `I`—to make a new commit `AI`:

```
          AI   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--o--*--o   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I   [abandoned]
```

Commits `A` through `I` remain in your repository, findable only through the `feature` and `HEAD` reflogs, for another 30+ days, if you need them back; but now `git log master..feature` shows just the one commit `AI`.  The snapshot in `AI` matches the snapshot in `I` but it looks like you did everything all in one amazing commit.

---

<sup>7</sup>Git being the tool-set that it is, there are several ways to make a new commit "be" a merge.  The most straightforward is to drop below the level of `git commit` itself, into the component parts that make a new commit, but you can also create a `.git/MERGE_HEAD` file with hash IDs in it.  None of this is designed for everyday, casual use, though.

<sup>8</sup>The usual one is to use `git merge --squash`, which lets you make `AI` come after the end of `master`, but generally uses a new branch name:

```
             AI   <-- completed-feature (HEAD)
            /
...--o--*--o   <-- master
         \
          A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I   <-- feature
```

Because branch names don't really matter—it's commit hash IDs that matter; branch names just *record* them for you—it *is* possible to do all this without using a second branch name.  But it's usually not wise to abandon a commit and have to hunt it down in the reflogs; it's too easy to goof things up this way.  If you start looking in your reflogs, you'll generally find many [twisty little passages, all alike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure) and it can be very tricky to find the *right* ones.

Comment: This must be a duplicate of something you posted earlier.  Wait...let me check.